# Mouse is rotated by 90 degrees

Tags: mouse

My mouse has recently started a very strange behaviour in that left = up, right = down, up = right and down = left. i.e. it's like my mouse is rotated by 90 degrees. I have tried uninstalling the mouse, run spybot and still no joy. It's rather frustrating and I'm going loopy - literally.

Comment: The Quick fix: rotate your mouse 90 degrees in your hand.

Comment: what platform ? If you have more than one OS, does it happen on one as well as the other ? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers (if you aren't using generic) ?

Answer (score 6):

Check the mouse settings. There are some mouse drivers that let you change the direction of movement (or rotate the direction of movement). I think this is for use with trackballs.

There is also a program, [Sakasa Mouse](http://download.cnet.com/SakasaMouse/3000-2056_4-10599613.html), that will rotate the mouse movement. The program is intended as a joke so check if someone installed it to mess with you. You shouldn't install it to fix the problem though, because as GwenKillerby states below, it's full of malware.

Barring that, you could turn your monitor 90 degrees the opposite direction and use the computer while lying on your side. ;-)

Comment: Sakasa is chock full of **malware** and *other goodies* https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/d8c302612cebb0d020b50531bab46c525d4cf8c94e09f60677f565a37ad21a9d/analysis/1480547906/

Comment: Thanks for the update GwenKillerby. I've updated the answer to recommend against using it.

Comment: @GwenKillerby Based on the virustotal link, looks to be mostly installer-embedded adware (untick the boxes while installing). The Potentially-Unwanted-Program entries can be ignored - they tend to detect 'prank' programs under that banner.

Comment: famous last words, Bob. Love your trusting soul. 13 of 35 antivirus programs report that it is BAD, very BAD. one or two might be false positives, but fully one third of them.... Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I had that. Happened after the screen was rotated, and then rotated back to normal. Mouse wouldn't rotate back to normal.

Rotated the screen several times to different degrees of rotation, and then back to normal. Somehow shook it up and it came back to normal.

Don't know how it happened and the fix makes no sense, but it worked. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a fix but I don't exactly know how or why it works. So I've had this problem with my mouse many times. and I've tried just about everything the rotating screen updating drivers and yes restarting my computer and waiting ten seconds. none of them worked. however it seemed to just have fixed itself over time, which was strange. but it made sense since the issue would usually occur when my mouse had taken abusive force such as dropping it or making very fast movements with it, leading me to suspect its a hardware problem.

So I decided to take it apart and just gut the whole thing out and take a look (I have very minimal knowledge in computers and electronics) I also decided to treat it as a learning moment seeing how a mouse works and how the buttons and inputs worked. the scroll wheel was the most fascinating.

Anyways my main focus was the tracking laser which to my surprise was actually just an LED in front of a reflector. so I took everything out to get to the reflector looked at it and tried to see any signs of rotation couldn't find any but I noticed it had a slot a bit bigger than the actually reflector so it would move around a bit and I'm assuming when I drop or jerk the mouse it moves which in turn might cause a rotation of the reflection (don't ask me how It's just a guess)

Anyways so I just took the reflector out and not knowing what to do I just put it back in and plugged in the mouse and it worked again idk how. I coulda sworn I just put it in the way I found it I must've stabilized it by accident or brushed of a piece off dust in the reflector idk. but anyways it just worked.

**So I guess just take it apart, gut everything out and put it back in ¯_(ツ)_/¯**

How to take apart mouse:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Take-apart-an-optical-mouse/

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen with a wireless USB mouse -- same issue with two different computers (Win 10). In my case it was fixed but turning the mouse itself off and on using the switch on the bottom. Sounds obvious, but I realized I never actually turn the mouse off, I normally just unplug the dongle and stick it back into the storage slot on the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

My Zebronics wireless mouse recently started behaving in similar way that you told. I also did shaking or rotating my laptop, restarting it but did nothing. So I just simply took off the battery from the mouse, blown air inside it (to remove dust) and putted cell (battery) again. And it worked ! :D

Answer (score 0):

The "turn it off and turn it back on again" strategy is sometimes the right answer for a wireless mouse.

It just worked on my wife's mouse.  I'm a hero!  Or less of an idiot or something.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer].

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you earn enough reputation, you will gain privileges to upvote answers you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](https://superuser.com/help/why-vote).