# Mouse rotated 90 degrees

Tags: windows-7, mouse, rotate

Three hours ago I opened a PDF file and my mouse changed its movement, like moving it left is down, etc.  I have been fighting with this problem ever since. I have read many forums but nothing helped.  I thought it might be some hotkey in Adobe or something, but didn't find anything about that.

I have tried all USB ports, reinstalling the mouse drivers several times, restarting my notebook, and changing rotation of the screen, but it didn't help.  The touchpad is working normally, the other optic mouse, too, but this one just doesn't want to.

I also tried some programs which can invert the mouse axis, but they only worked for the touchpad, not the mouse.

Any ideas how to turn it back? I don't want to hold my mouse in 270° clockwise for the rest of its life.  I'm using Win7.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, can you check the optical outlet on the bottom of the mouse? Sometimes stray dust (and hair) gets in there and can cause some serious looking problems.

Comment: It is completly clean, the mouse is +-month old also, so nothing had a chance to get inside yet. :/

Comment: Strange. What happens when you flip the screen 90°?

Comment: The mouse flips 90° more together with the screen, I have rotated the screen many times, but the mouse is still flipping together with it, not going back to original axis.

Comment: Worth a shot. Seeing as it's around a month old, try returning it? If the touchpad and other mouse is fine it seems to indicate an issue with the hardware itself.

Comment: Its probably the only way to solve it... I was just hoping there is some another solution, as it happend out of nothing, when opening a pdf file, the axis reversed... Thank you for the tips anyways.

Comment: Did you try the PDF on another machine to see if it replicated the issue? I'm thinking the PDF opening was a coincidence

Comment: I tried opening that pdf with another optical mouse, but it didnt happen, so you are probably right about coincidence. Now Im opening that file with the broken mouse and its not changing back, seems the pdf has nothing to do with it... Guess I will have to return the mouse

Comment: Use the different mouse. Unless the mouse in question is special, bin it

Comment: Go to control panel, disability options, and see if something is there that causes this. Its the only thing I can think of other than a defect in the mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouse is rotated by 90 degrees](http://superuser.com/questions/151758/mouse-is-rotated-by-90-degrees)

Answer (score 1):

I had this with a Konig mouse, and I mailed them, and they mailed me a fix back, it was a small executable, which fixed it.
It helps if you can tell them the product id or the serial number. If all else fails, take a picture of the mouse and drag and drop it on (upload) it to Google Image Search.