# Mouse movements 90• rotated (Definitely caused by hardware)

Tags: hardware-failure, hardware-acceleration, hardware-virtualization

My external wifi mouse works fine but when I move it to right the cursor moves to up side and other ways have same issue. I tried it with on windows,Linux OS on my laptop and on windows on my friend's laptop and also tried my LG G3 phone(android 4.4.4) and all of them has this annoying issue. I think my mouse need calibration but I don't know how I do.

**My mouse model** (A4 G6SAVER - MODEL NO:G6-70D)

EDIT: Unfortunately, installing driver doesn't solve this issue on Windows 8. (I did everything that shown on the instructions of installing.)

Comment: Is it A4tech wireless optical mouse? Are you sure the model is G6-700 or G6-70D?

Comment: Yes it is D not 0 but it is so small on mouse so I read it wrong

Comment: So the driver is at http://www.a4tech.com/download%20driver.asp?cmodnum=g6-70d and the manual at https://fccid.io/document.php?id=873456

Comment: If the driver cannot resolve the problem, it is hardware failure, bring it to technician or buy a new one.

Comment: Thanks @Jusup. The manual says it supports widow and up to vista but previously I used it on windows 7 and didn't install any things and vanilla it worked. I didn't use it for long time  after buy laptop and recently I tried but it has  this issue

Comment: I had already bought new one but I like this so if there is a solution to correct it I will be happy :)

Comment: Try to install the driver using compatibility mode, right click the driver, select properties, at compatibility tab set it for Windows Vista, I have tried at Windows 10.

Comment: I will try this but not now I have some works so I need to go. Thanks @Jusup. I will add result of this

Comment: There is a similar question, 180 degree rotation. http://superuser.com/questions/406502/how-can-i-reverse-mouse-movement-x-y-axis-system-wide-win-7-x64

Comment: Thanks @Chris.C the sakasa works well but it rotate my internal mouse. Thanks I work on this :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouse is rotated by 90 degrees](http://superuser.com/questions/151758/mouse-is-rotated-by-90-degrees)

Comment: @MyUserName when i write this i did NOT enough time to do research sorry for that. And I wanna REcalibre it to works all of them. But thanks for your feedback